# Angular Filtering based on current date

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

I have an app which is needs to filter items based on whether they are equal to the current day or in the past. My date value is formatted as  a string like "12/19/2014".

I have a filter set-up but it is returning an empty array since the date formatting isn't matching correctly.

```
app.filter('publishFilter', function() { 

   return function(items) {

    var newItems = [];

    var currentDate = new Date();

    angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
      if (item <= currentDate) {
        newItems.push(item);
      }
    });

    return newItems;
  }
});
```

Comment: When you do date comparison you would need to convert `item` which is a string to date as well. I.e try `if (new Date(item) <= currentDate) {`

Comment: It looks like it iterated over each number and stored them in the array ["1","2","1","9","2","0","1","4"]

Comment: That is probably because items is not what you think it is. Did you try console.log items? Also how are you consuming this filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When comparing dates try to convert both sides to date. Assuming items is the list of string representing dates try:-

```
app.filter('publishFilter', function() { 

   return function(items) {

    if(!angular.isArray(items)) return [];

    var currentDate = new Date();
    currentDate.setHours(0,0,0,0); //Just normalize the time offset, since item is just time.

    return items.filter(function(item){
       return new Date(item) <= currentDate;
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: I've added my template. This returned empty arrays as well.

Comment: Ofcourse you are doing it wrong. `{{blo.date | publishFilter }}` You are providing just one date string to the filter. Now i am confused what are you trying to do?

Comment: Maybe this is better off in the controller than as a filter. I was going about this the wrong way. I am trying to limit the results provided to ng-repeat. I'll still need the same kind of logic, I'm guessing just in the controller.

Comment: @byrdr Yes do it in the controller for the list of items.. unless you want to run the filter every digest cycle. In the view you would generally use it with ng-repeat. bascially you need to use the filter with list of items not on single item. Because on a single item there is nothing to filter

Comment: @byrdr No problem. Do you think i need to keep this answer (atleast you got a shorter code with comparison issue you originally had)?

Comment: Yes, it make things more concise. This line if(!angular.isArray(items)), you are basically saying if only a single item is returned in the params then return an empty array. Is that right?

Comment: @byrdr It is just to ensure only arrays are passed to avoid any exceptions. Also note [array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) not supported on IE8 and below unless you add the shim mentioned in the document.

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished much safer and simpler if you use the momentJS library. Programming against time is a lot like programming against money, you should tread lightly as the slightest mistake can and will introduce business logic errors into your code.

```
_.forEach(items, function(item){
   if(moment().isBefore(moment(item){
       //do something
   }
)}
```